# Android Studio and Genymotion Plugin

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, genymotion

There seems to be a bug with the plugin when launching the reg.exe process. I develop on Windows 8.1 and my path to Genymotion folder is:

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion.
```

But the launch process seems to add both a backslash and regular slash to create a path to reg.exe. Which makes it a faulty path and ends with not being able to launch the plugin.

Copied from eventlog:

13:40:39 Genymotion: Loading Genymotion library
13:40:39 Genymotion: Genymotion directory: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
13:40:39 Genymotion: Trying to initialize engine
13:40:39 Genymotion: Launch process: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion/reg.exe
13:40:39 NullPointerException: null

Comment: You are using the Android Studio plugin right? The slash should not be a problem. What is it actually happening? Can you explain how to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today. To solve it I did the following steps:

1. Uninstalled the Genymotion plugin from Android Studio
2. Downloaded "Genymotion" with Virtual Box and installed it (https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download - 117.47MB download)
3. Rebooted my PC
4. Started Android Studio and reinstalled the Genymotion plugins.
5. Started again Android Studio as an Administrator

After these operations the Genymotion icon on Android Studio toolbar worked.
I also tried to run Android Studio as a normal user and it worked successfully.

Hope this helps